# In django, how to show the static images in webpage under apache?

Tags: django, apache

I am new to django and confused about the setting of static files. Under the django's server, the png which located in my app's "static/" subdirectory displayed correctly in webpage. But when it goes to apache, no image was found. What is the matter?
Version of django I use is **1.3**. All settings related to static and media in "settings.py" are the default value. I just put the image files in "static/" subdirectory of my app.
Eagerly for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Static File Hosting an Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682809/django-static-file-hosting-an-apache) and too many others to count.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Apache to do it. These links will put you on the right track:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/#serving-media-files
- http://programmingzen.com/2009/07/22/serving-django-static-files-through-apache/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since django 1.3, django has had a static files feature.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

And BTW, mod_python has been depreciated for mod_wsgi for django apps.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/