# Django support static file for production

Tags: python, django

In my settings.py,

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/khantthulinn/webapps/static_media/'
STATIC_URL = '/home/khantthulinn/webapps/static_media/'
```

In my urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    #Media
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

)+ static(settings.STATIC_ROOT, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

After that, in my web server, I have copied static files.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Everything is okay and I see all correctly.

It become problem when I change DEBUG = False.

I read this already but I don't understand.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/

I have read solution from here too.

[Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

> With debug turned off Django won't handle static files for you any
>   more - your production web server (Apache or something) should take
>   care of that.

I wana try that. How shall I do?

I don't want to run this since it is insecure.

```
manage.py runserver --insecure
```

Comment: `your production web server (Apache or something) should take care of that` so you need to configure Apache or something to handle static.

Comment: yes. Could you please guide me to configure apache? I am hosting in webfaction.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an alias for `/static` to the path where they are locally. Read this answer:

[Django Static File Hosting an Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682809/django-static-file-hosting-an-apache)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using apache with mod_wsgi, you'll need to change your `wsgi.py` file.

all you need to insert are those lines at the end of your file:

`from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())`

Note that I'm using Django 1.8(LTS) and I'm not quite sure if those functions are still in the actual version.