# Django files not found when served with Apache

Tags: django, apache, django-staticfiles

I deployed my Django project on a Linux server using Linode. When I run it by the `python manage.py runserver` command on port 8000 everything looks fine. However, when I use apache2 I get the following error when loading the website:

```
FileNotFoundError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'research_files/data.xlsx'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://453.33.13.202/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'research_files/data.xlsx'
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-available I've created a django_project.conf file which has the following instructions:

```
Alias /research_files/ /home/alexa/django_project/research_files/
<Directory /home/alexa/django_project/django_project/research_files>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/alexa/django_project/django_project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/alexa/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py>
WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/alexa/django_project python-home=/home/alexa/django_project/venv
WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

Then I've enabled that file by running `sudo a2ensite django_project` and also given access to the folder by running:

```
sudo chown :www-data django_project/research_files
sudo chmod 664 django_project/research_files
```

What may be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is the extra / in the first line after research_files, so instead /research_files/ it would be /research_files. This could be a guide also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5684257/15020017